# Audit a share Excel workbook

Tags: excel, office365, audit-logging

I'm looking for a way to audit who makes changes to an Excel worksheet and what changes they made. From what I can see the Review - > Show Changes will show me what I've done but not what other users who have worked on the worksheet. We have been having some issues with changes being made but nobody acknowledging the changes. As one solution someone mentioned something called a "who checkbox" what is this and where can I find it?

Thanks